# numpy.histogram2d() returning a histogram of all zeros

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, histogram

I'm trying to reproduce a phenomenon I've encountered when constructing 2D histograms using numpy.histogram2d, specifically when using the "bins" parameter.  When I use an integer for the bins parameter (e.g. bins=20), I see the expected 2D histogram.  However, I want my histogram to have consistently-sized bins, so I want to create the histogram with set minimum and maximum x- and y-values.  Currently, I'm creating the bin divisions using numpy.linspace to get arrays of evenly-spaced values.

```
x_bins = np.linspace(min_range, max_range, num=num_bins+1) #numpy is imported as np
y_bins = np.linspace(0, max_even, num=num_bins+1)
```

I use these arrays for the bins argument in numpy.histogram2d.

```
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=(x_bins, y_bins))
```

The arrays x and y are arrays of numbers between the values of min_range and max_range (for x), and between 0 and max_even (for y).  When I define the bins with arrays, some of the histograms I generate have all zeros.  All x and y arrays are the same length, and the only thing I can think of that changes is the number ranges fed into numpy.histogram2d.
Numbers in these x and y ranges yield histograms that are not all zeros:

x: min_range = 0.07, max_range = 142.095; y: 0, max_even = 471.64

x: min_range = 0.218, max_range = 195.178; y: 0, max_even = 1493.489

Numbers in these ranges yield histograms with all zeros:

x: min_range = 0.006, max_range = 6.916; y: 0, max_even = 1.101

x: min_range = 0, max_range = 5.58; y: 0, max_even = 1.205

The x and y arrays are both numpy arrays.  Printing out the x and y bins and values shows that all the x and y values should fall into the defined bins.  Trying to replicate the error with arrays of random values within the ranges of interest wasn't successful, so I apologize for the lack of examples; any suggestions for replication are welcome.  What might cause the histogram2d function to return a histogram of all zeros?

**EDIT**

I tried using the range parameter of histogram2d to define the min and max x and y values, and using an integer for the bins parameter (code below).  That had no effect on the histograms with all zeros.

```
hist, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=10, range=[[min_range, max_range], [0, max_even]])
```

Comment: It will be much easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I agree, and have been trying to write an example that can reproduce the problem.  I'll keep trying and update my post should that happen.

Comment: What are `min_range` and `max_range`?

Comment: Have you explored numpy.digitize to allocate your data to bins?

Comment: @TlsChris I can find the bin numbers of each x and y value with numpy.digitize, the trick is converting those arrays of bin numbers into a 2D histogram with counts for each bin.

Comment: @Ardweaden min_range and max_range are the upper and lower boundaries for the x-values, respectively.  max_even is the upper bound for the y-values.  I've edited my post to make that clearer.

Comment: So I didn't quite answer the question (wasn't able to reproduce the histogram of all zeros under the conditions of interest), but I did find a workaround by not converting the lists of x- and y-values into numpy arrays.  I'm not sure why that helps, but if anyone has any idea you're welcome to voice it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is a case that will generate a zero array. If the range parameters were swapped by axis or repeated this could generate a 2d histogram of zeroes with certain x and y arrays.

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)
x = 5*np.random.rand(40)+5.
y = 3*np.random.rand(40)+10.

x_min = x.min()
x_max = x.max()

y_min = y.min()
y_max = y.max()

np.histogram2d( x , y, bins = [ 5, 3 ], range = [[ x_min, x_max ], [ x_min, x_max ]])
#                                                  x_min & x_max both times!!

# (array([[0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0.],
#         [0., 0., 0.]]),
#  array([5.02359428, 5.99979628, 6.97599828, 7.95220028, 8.92840228, 9.90460429]),
#  array([5.02359428, 6.65059762, 8.27760095, 9.90460429]))

# Corrected version
np.histogram2d( x , y, bins = [ 5, 3 ], range = [[ x_min, x_max ], [ y_min, y_max ]])

# (array([[5., 5., 2.],
#         [1., 4., 3.],
#         [0., 3., 2.],
#         [2., 0., 1.],
#         [5., 5., 2.]]),
# array([5.02359428, 5.99979628, 6.97599828, 7.95220028, 8.92840228, 9.90460429]),
# array([10.0613174 , 11.01588476, 11.97045212, 12.92501948]))
```